# How to put a bound with RegionPlot-Edited

Tags: plotting, graphics

I was trying this simple code to plot the contours within a specific region bounded by a limit

```
 Show[ContourPlot[X1, {a, 1*^-6, 0.02}, {b, 1*^-6, 0.02}, 
  Contours -> {5, 5*10^2, 5*10^3}, ContourLabels -> True, 
  ContourShading -> {None, Lighter@Lighter@ColorData[97][1]}, 
  ScalingFunctions -> {"Log10", "Log10"}], 
 RegionPlot[X1 > Br\[Tau]3\[Mu], {a, 1*^-6, 0.1}, {b, 1*^-6, 0.1}]]
```

with functions X1 and X2 are defined as

```
X1 = 1.3335698177171183`*^8 a^2 - 3.636178913116437`*^8 a b + 
  3.280532719877099`*^8 b^2  

X2 = 2.5163488578437388`*^8 Abs[a]^2
```

and the limit is given by

```
Br\[Tau]3\[Mu] = 2.1*10^-8.
```

But it doesn't seem that the `RegionPlot` is acting as it should be, means, I don't get the clear idea about the region which is excluded by the limit. Is there any way to do it more efficiently ? Thanks.

**Edits**

Since `RegionPlot` and `ScalingFunctions` are not compatible with each other and as the value of X1 is still larger with previously used range of 'a' and 'b', I made some changes to get the contour within the plot.

```
Show[ContourPlot[X1, {a, 1*^-8, 2.8*^-8}, {b, 1*^-8, 1.8*^-8}, 
  Contours -> {Br\[Tau]3\[Mu]}, 
  ContourShading -> {None, Lighter@Lighter@ColorData[97][1]}, 
  ContourLabels -> True, PlotPoints -> 100, PlotRange -> Full, 
  ScalingFunctions -> {"Log10", "Log10"}]]
```

Now my question is :
Is there any way to generate that reference plot (in my previous post) where the excluded region is shown by the shaded region. Also contours of different orders (10^-7,10^-6 etc.) are shown in the same plot by different contour styles for the comparison purpose ?

Answer (score 2):

Ah, I think I understand the problem a bit better now.

The 2 main issues I see:

1. I recommend using `ContourPlot` rather than `RegionPlot` in this case because `RegionPlot` does not support `ScalingFunctions` (although I'm not totally sure why it doesn't).
2. Your limit of $Br\tau 3\mu = 2.1\times 10^{-8}$ is smaller than anything plotted on the graph. `(X1 /. {a -> 10^-6, b -> 10^-6}) > Br\[Tau]3\[Mu]` yields `True`. Your graphs have the smallest `a` and smallest `b` as $10^{-6}$, and X1 becomes $9.8\times 10^{-5}$ there, which is still larger than your value. So either the entire plotted zone is being excluded, or else the entire plotted zone is included (I'm not sure whether you're trying to colour the included zone or excluded zone).

Let's pretend that your excluded zone is anything greater than 0.01:

```
X1 = 1.3335698177171183`*^8 a^2 - 3.636178913116437`*^8 a b + 
  3.280532719877099`*^8 b^2

X2 = 2.5163488578437388`*^8 Abs[a]^2

Br\[Tau]3\[Mu] = 0.01

Show[
 ContourPlot[
    X1,
    {a, 1*^-6, 0.1},
    {b, 1*^-6, 0.1},
    Contours -> {0.01},
    ContourShading -> {Blue, Green},
    PlotPoints -> 100,
    PlotRange -> Full,
    ScalingFunctions -> {"Log10", "Log10"}
  ],
  ContourPlot[
    X1,
    {a, 1*^-6, 0.1},
    {b, 1*^-6, 0.1},
    Contours -> {5, 5*10^2, 5*10^3},
    ContourLabels -> True,
    ContourShading -> {None, Lighter@Lighter@ColorData[97][1]},
    PlotPoints -> 100,
    PlotRange -> Full,
    ScalingFunctions -> {"Log10", "Log10"}
  ]
]
```

[image: Plot with exclusion zone in green and plotted first.]

The main things to note:

1. I've plotted the exclusion zone first so that it's underneath. If this isn't what you want, plot it second so that it's on top.
2. In this scenario, anything that is blue is included, and anything that is green or has green underneath it is excluded. Because I'm exluding anything greater than 0.01, almost the entire plot is in the exclusion zone. If I decrease the exclusion level more, even more would be green.
3. I adjusted both plots to plot the same `a` and `b` ranges because I felt it looked weird to have them cover different ranges, but you can easily change this back.

We can see the same plot if we have the exclusion zone charted second:

[image: Plot with exclusion zone in green plotted second.]

This ends up covering everything that got plotted before. I assume this is undesirable, but I'm not sure.

**EDIT 01:**

Is this what you're looking for?

```
Show[
 ContourPlot[
  X1,
  {a, 1*^-8, 2.8*^-8},
  {b, 1*^-8, 1.8*^-8},
  Contours -> {Br\[Tau]3\[Mu]},
  ContourShading -> {None, Lighter@Lighter@ColorData[97][1]},
  PlotPoints -> 100,
  PlotRange -> Full,
  PlotRangePadding -> None,
  ScalingFunctions -> {"Log10", "Log10"}
  ],
 ContourPlot[
  X1,
  {a, 1*^-8, 2.8*^-8},
  {b, 1*^-8, 1.8*^-8},
  Contours -> {1.*^-8, 1.5*^-8, 2.*^-8, 2.5*^-8},
  ContourLabels -> All,
  ContourShading -> None,
  ContourStyle -> 
   Thread[Directive[
     AbsoluteThickness[1.5], {Black, Dashed, 
      Dashing[{0.02, 0.02, 0.008, 0.02}], Dashing[{0.03, 0.03}]}]],
  PlotPoints -> 100,
  PlotRange -> Full,
  ScalingFunctions -> {"Log10", "Log10"}]]
```

[image: Updated version of plot.]

**EDIT 02:**

Adding in the extra contours:

```
X1 = 1.3335698177171183`*^8 a^2 - 3.636178913116437`*^8 a b + 
  3.280532719877099`*^8 b^2

X2 = 2.5163488578437388`*^8 Abs[a]^2

Br\[Tau]3\[Mu] = 2.1*10^-8.

arange = {a, 1*^-8, 1*^-6};
brange = {b, 1*^-8, 5*^-7};
Show[ContourPlot[X1, arange, brange, Contours -> {Br\[Tau]3\[Mu]}, 
  ContourShading -> {None, Lighter@Lighter@ColorData[97][1]}, 
  PlotPoints -> 100, PlotRange -> Full, PlotRangePadding -> None, 
  ScalingFunctions -> {"Log10", "Log10"}], 
 ContourPlot[X1, arange, brange, 
  Contours -> {1.*^-8, 1.5*^-8, 2.*^-8, 2.5*^-8, 10.^-7, 10.^-6, 
    10.^-5}, ContourLabels -> All, ContourShading -> None, 
  ContourStyle -> 
   Thread[Directive[
     AbsoluteThickness[1.5], {Black, Dashed, 
      Dashing[{0.02, 0.02, 0.008, 0.02}], Dashing[{0.03, 0.03}], Blue,
       Pink, Green, Red}]], PlotPoints -> 100, PlotRange -> Full, 
  ScalingFunctions -> {"Log10", "Log10"}]]
```

[image: Contour plot with additional contours.]

Comment: Thanks again for your reply. I've edited the post to mention my further concerns. Hope that is clear, otherwise please let me know.

Comment: @Joy I've added another attempt. Is this close to what you were looking for?

Comment: not exactly. What I was trying to get are following:

Comment: Can I add contours 1.*^-5, 1*^-4, 1.*^-3, 1*^-2 etc. on this plot ?

Comment: @Joy Not as it is. The plot does not contain those values so adding those contours would do nothing. Those contour lines are far off the top right edge of the graph. If you want those contours, expand the range of a and b. However, any contour over 2.1x10^-8 is in your forbidden region anyways, so I’m not totally sure why you want to plot those.

Comment: Okay, I was guessing that will be a bit tricky! The reason I want to plot those contours is, I want to show a comparison plot. As you said, any contour over 2.1x10^-8 is in your forbidden region, that is true and that particular value is coming from experiment. Now, I'm calculating theoretically and getting some values ~10^-6,10^-5 etc. So, I want to show what is the current constraint/limiting value and what is possible in future in the same plot! Could I make myself clear ?

Comment: @Joy Well, the coding to add extra contours is trivial: just add the contours you want to `Contours ->{...}` and expand the range of both graphs. It just depends on what exactly you would like to show in your plot. I've updated my answer with a few of the powers of 10 that you mentioned.